# Chinese conversion in MultiByteToWideChar

Tags: visual-c++, utf-8, character-encoding, messagebox, wchar-t

I'm trying to display a Chinese text in the MessageBoxW. But I can't correctly convert it from UTF-8 to wchar_t. At the same time, the original wchar_t Chinese is displayed correctly.
I played with different MultiByteToWideChar flags but with the same result. What the reason of the incorrect conversion?
[image]

Comment: Is the source file saved in UTF-8?  Did you compile with the `/utf-8` option if using the Microsoft compiler?

Comment: Also please post code as text not images.

Comment: Hierogliphs are thin matter and what you see could depend on your settings. That's why I've posted the code as image this time to be sure that you see exactly what I see.

Answer (score 1):

`char text[] = "文本"` is only UTF-8 if the *source file* is encoded in UTF-8.  Since your title string displays correctly your encoding is the default Chinese legacy encoding on Windows, and the `text` string contains bytes in that encoding, and not UTF-8, so `MultiByteToWideChar` fails.  You can see that the function returns zero if you set the flag to check for invalid characters, which happens if it isn't really UTF-8:

```
int ret = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS, text, -1, wtext, 1000);
```

The Microsoft compiler has options to specify source and execution character set, and a `/utf-8` option (recommended):

```
/source-charset:<iana-name>|.nnnn      set source character set  
/execution-charset:<iana-name>|.nnnn   set execution character set  
/utf-8                                 set source and execution character set to UTF-8
```

Multiple options to fix.  #2 and #3 assume the Microsoft compiler.  Other compilers may vary.

1. Use `char text[] = u8"文本";` since your existing default encoding supports Chinese.  The source characters will be interpreted in that encoding and then re-encoded in UTF-8 with this notation.  If the source is sent to someone with different OS default encoding, it will not work for them.
2. Re-save the source as UTF-8 w/ BOM.  The MS compiler will detect the BOM (byte order mark used as a UTF-8 signature) and process the source as if `/utf-8` was specified.  `text` will contain UTF-8 bytes.  Title will display correctly.
3. Re-save as UTF-8 (no BOM) and compile with the `/utf-8` switch to inform the compiler to decode the source as UTF-8 instead of the default encoding.
4. Use ASCII-only source and escape codes to specify the Chinese character explicitly.

Example of #4 that will compile correctly no matter the OS default encoding:

```c
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    char text[] = "\xe6\x96\x87\xe6\x9c\xac";
    wchar_t wtext[1000];
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, text, -1, wtext, 1000);
    MessageBoxW(NULL, wtext, L"\u6a19\u984c", MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The way 1 is that I searched for. Way 2 doesn't work for some reason while 3 and 4 work well.

Comment: By the way, MultiByteToWideChar returns 3 when I see "??" even with MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS